# Заменить символы в TextBox для ввода пароля C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Так исторически сложилось, что необходимо использовать TextBox для ввода логина и пароля. Как правильно организовать замену символов в текстовом поле ввода пароля. 
Набросал код.

```
public class TextToPasswordCharConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = new string('*', value?.ToString().Length ?? 0);
        return str;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return new object();
    }
}
```

Свойство пароля во вью модели

```
public string PasswordField
    {
        get => passwordValue;
        set
        {
            passwordValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Наблюдатель

```
 public abstract class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="140,174,30,10">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="PasswordField" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" Converter="{StaticResource TextToPasswordCharConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Код работает, но вопрос в том, что не знаю как правильно реализовать конвертер. Сейчас он при вводе одного символа пишет в поле 13 символов сразу '*' и удалить их не возможно клавишей backSpace.  А необходимо при вводе символа печатать в текстовое поле всегда символ '*', и возможность его стирать.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать [PasswordBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox)? Конечно в условиях MVVM не так просто с ним работать, но всё же [есть способы](https://habr.com/ru/post/169231).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал немного проще. Скачал шрифт passdot.ttf. Добавил его в ресурсы приложения, подключил в разметке,

```
FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#password"
```

где запретил копирование, вырезание и вставку.

```
  <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="140,174,30,10" 
             FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#password"
             CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="OnPreviewExecuted"
             ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="PasswordField" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <!--Disable CTRL+C -->
            <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand"
                        Key="C"
                        Modifiers="Control" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
```

Пока для теста во вью прокинул событие, после заменю на команду.

```
/// <summary>
    ///     Forbid Copy, Cut, Paste
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnPreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy ||
            e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut ||
            e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

С password box пока заморачиваться не стал. Дальше захеширую строку в поле. Что бы в памяти текст не хранить.